# How do I format man page for printing on custom page size?

Tags: groff

I know that I can specify the custom page size to `groff` by passing `-P-p...` option.
When I run the following command:

`gunzip -dc /usr/share/man/man1/fswebcam.1.gz | groff -mandoc -P-p612p,396p >fswebcam.ps`

I get the man page formatted as if for full page, but then truncated to my custom page size.
How do I tell the `groff` that it needs to respect new pages size and adjust the margins appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the PostScript page size is independent of setting the troff page size, which must also be done.
Some groff macro packages allow you to pass options in to set the line length and page length. `man groff_man` says you can use `-rLL=10c`, for example, to set the line length to 10cm, but there is no option for page length.

In this case, the simplest thing to do is use basic troff commands to set these values before passing in the rest of the document:

```bsh
( printf '.pl 612p\n.ll 396p\n'
  gunzip -dc /usr/share/man/man1/fswebcam.1.gz) |
groff -mandoc -P -p612p,396p  >fswebcam.ps
```

Comment: Had to modify it to `( printf '.pl 612p\n.ll 4.5i\n.in 0.0i\n.po 0.5i\n' ; gunzip -dc /usr/share/man/man1/fswebcam.1.gz) | groff -mandoc -P-p612p,396p >fswebcam.ps` but it got me where I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

[groff(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/groff) says to use the `papersize` macro package, which is documented in [groff_tmac(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/groff_tmac.5.html).

The package is automatically loaded, and uses the `paper` definition to set the virtual paper size, so you'd use e.g.

```
groff -mandoc -dpaper=a6 -P-pa6
```

to use A6 paper.

Comment: I feel like this should be the correct answer, but it is not working for me. I need to print on a halfletter (which properly shows up in paperconfig FWIW). I tried `groff -mandoc -dpaper=612p,396p -P-p612p,396p` also `-dpaper=halfletter` and get `Unknown paper size` message and no proper formatting.

Comment: @user143266, according to [groff_tmac(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/groff_tmac.5.html) the paper sizes are listed in [groff_font(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/groff_font.5.html), "halfletter" isn't in that list. The `-dpaper=612p,396p` notation should work though.

Comment: it should but it doesn't. Tried on on several different systems, have to resort to dirty hack described in the accepted answer.